# Buy shares and bonds in non citizens countries

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, bonds, government-bonds, stock-dividend

I am from Sri Lanka and I invested in stock market and bond in Sri Lanka. But I really like to buy other countries shares and bonds. Is it possible to buy those thing without citizenship.

I know some brokers give to buy shares with dividends but those shares are not real shares. When I brought it doesn’t not have actual company shares. How can I buy actual shares.

What are counties can I buy shares and what are companies.